# How do you find feature names for Decision Tree Classification?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to find the feature information for my decision trees. More specifically, I want to be able to tell what feature 183 is if it appears in my tree visualization. I have tried dtModel.getInputCol() but receive the following error.

`AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassificationModel' object has no attribute 'getInputCol'`

This is my current code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Create initial Decision Tree Model
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", maxDepth=3)

# Train model with Training Data
dtModel = dt.fit(trainingData)
display(dtModel)
```

If you can help or need more information, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See this example taken from [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-decision-tree.html#classification) (I try to have the name consistent with your code, especially `featuresCol="features"`).

I assume you have some code like this (before the code you posted in the question):

```
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol="inputFeatures", outputCol="features", maxCategories=4).fit(data)
```

After this step, you have the `"features"` as indexed features, and then you feed to the `DecisionTreeClassifier` (like your posted code):

```
# Train a DecisionTree model.
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="features")
```

What you're looking for is **`inputFeatures`** above, which is the original features before being indexed. If you want to print it, simply do something like:

```
sc.parallelize(inputFeatures, 1).saveAsTextFile("absolute_path")
```

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I am using vector assembler instead of vector indexer for my pipeline which is similar, but I know I need to get the inputFeatures but I do not know how to recall InputFeatures. How would you go about displaying inputFeatures?

Comment: It should be a list of string, just print it out, i'm adding to the answer

Comment: @ChristianTatham Hi, does it answer your question? Please consider performing an action [either vote it down if not answered or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: Won't be able to access the problem for a bit, I promise I will test the solution once I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipeline to engage its `.transform()` method.

Via your comments, you prepped `trainingData` for `DecisionTreeClassifier()` via `VectorAssembler()`.  Embed within a `Pipeline` to get the goodies you want via its `.transform()` method.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["c1", "c2"], outputCol = 'features')
dtModel = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol = 'label', maxDepth = 3)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [vec_assembler, dtModel])
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
trainingData_transformed = pipeline_model.transform(trainingData)  # <-- Abracadabra!
```

Use `display(trainingData_transformed)` to see its new columns.  In addition, there are metadata.  Dig to get the dictionary of column indices.  Try

```
feature_map = trainingData_transformed.schema['features'].metadata['ml_attr']['attrs']
feature_map
```

to see something like

```
{'numeric': [{'idx': 0, 'name': 'c1'}, {'idx': 1, 'name': 'c2'}]}
```

The `feature_map` dictionary will have more structure if you have also added `StringIndexer` in `pipeline`, but you can probably take it from here.  The `feature_map` in your case should have an entry similar to `{idx: 183, 'name', 'the_col_that_matters'}`.